# Chosen.js dropdowns | how preserve data-placeholder?

Tags: jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I have five multiple selects, created dynamically with javascript. Next to each filter I have two links: "all" and "none". "All" places all the filters into the chosen box, to make it easier for users to exclude a value. "None" removes all options.

When I use "all" to add the filters, and then manually remove them, the data placeholder disappears and I get a blank filter box. If I click "all" and then "none", the data-placeholder persists. If I add and remove filters manually, it persists.

https://jsfiddle.net/09bmrq31/6/

The only DOM difference I can see is that the input field (div.chosen-container ul.chosen-choices li.search-field input) typically has a class of "default". This class is rendered "" when clicking "all". When clicking "none", the class goes back to "default". So I think this class is the culprit. Changing the class back to "default" in the DOM has no effect by itself but I guess some javascript process depends on this class.

I'm using chosen-material-design on top of chosen. But I've searched this CSS file and the regular chosen file for ".default" and it's not there, so I don't think this is a CSS issue.

Does anyone know what sets (or unsets) this class? This is a problem across three different apps and has been going on for weeks. Grateful for any help!

Javascript select code:

```
f.innerHTML += '<select id="'+filters[0][i]+'" class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:80%" data-placeholder="'+filters[1][i]+'"><option value=""></option></select>';
```

Chosen code:

```
  $(".chosen-select").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 10,
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
  });
```

Javascript all/none code:

```
d3.selectAll("div.all").on("click",function(){
  var whichSelect = this.id.substr(0,this.id.length-4);
  $("[id='"+whichSelect+"'] option").prop('selected',true);
  $("[id='"+whichSelect+"']").trigger('chosen:updated');

  var tempIndex = filters[0].indexOf(whichSelect);//whether it's company, portfolio, industry or country
  for (var i=0; i<filters[2][tempIndex].length; i++) { if (filters[6][tempIndex].indexOf(filters[2][tempIndex][i])==-1) { filters[6][tempIndex].push(filters[2][tempIndex][i]); }}
  filters[5][tempIndex].filterFunction(function(d){ return filters[6][tempIndex].indexOf(d)!=-1; });

  update();
});


d3.selectAll("div.none").on("click",function(){
  var whichSelect = this.id.substr(0,this.id.length-5);
  $("[id='"+whichSelect+"'] option").prop('selected',false);
  $("[id='"+whichSelect+"']").trigger('chosen:updated');
  var tempIndex = filters[0].indexOf(whichSelect);//whether it's company, portfolio, industry or country
  filters[6][tempIndex] = [];
  filters[5][tempIndex].filterAll();

  update();

});
```

Image of DOM with data-placeholder showing and class of "default":

[image: DOM of chosen select and div]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [updated your fiddle (revision 8)](https://jsfiddle.net/09bmrq31/7/), with a fix.

Problem: your original HTML has an empty element `<option value=""></option>` in the options, and your JS code to add all options (when user clicks on your "all" link/button) also includes that empty option, and that trips the library.

#### Solution

**You should exclude that `option` element when you call `.prop('selected', true)`**

In terms of code, you do that:

```
$("[id='"+whichSelect+"'] option").prop('selected',true);
```

And that unfortunately include the empty option. So, do that instead:

```
$("[id='"+whichSelect+"'] option:not([value=''])").prop('selected',true);
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                              This excludes the empty option
```

You could use any other way, perhaps it would be easier to add a class to that specific element, and use the class to select it more easily than with the selector above.

---

#### Why does that happen?

There is an internal consistency issue in the plugin (although it only applies for "incorrect" usage, so it's only half bad): some parts of the code seem to purposefully ignore this empty option, but another part takes it into account for total count of selected options. Result: depending on the previous state, this empty & invisible option is counted, and despite visually empty input field the library computes `choices_count() = 1` (instead of 0).

And behold the function that updates this `default` class, at line 942 of `chosen.jquery.js`:

```
Chosen.prototype.show_search_field_default = function() {
  if (this.is_multiple && this.choices_count() < 1 && !this.active_field) {
    this.search_field.val(this.default_text);
    return this.search_field.addClass("default");
  } else {
    this.search_field.val("");
    return this.search_field.removeClass("default");
  }
};
```

Because `choices_count()` is 1 instead of 0, the class is not added back, and you don't see the placeholder.

In short: **make sure your code does not include empty option in the list of selected items**